# Downloading music from the internet onto my computer

Tags: halacha, internet, music, gezel-stealing

I was online and I found the song [*Im Ein Ani Li Mi Li*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dii0NA1i6cA) by Shloime Gertner on **youtube**. Then I used a [conversion program](http://www.youtube-mp3.org/) to convert the video into an mp3 file and afterwards download the file to my computer. Is that considered stealing?